# horizontal scrollbar

Tags: css, html, scrollbar

How can I make an automatic horizontal scroll bar in my page if the content will overflow in its border.

```
<html>
     <body>
        <div style ="width: 20px; height:30px; border:1px solid black; overflow:auto">
            <!-- various of text here that can makes it go out the border-->
        </div>  
     </body>
</html>
```

What if the text in my content is too long, how can I make an automatic horizontal scrollbar?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

change your code into this:

```
 <html>
 <body>
    <div style ="width: 20px; height:30px; border:1px solid black; overflow-x:scroll">
        <!-- various of text here that can makes it go out the border-->
    </div>  
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 11):

Insert in the div style :

```
overflow-x:scroll;
```

Comment: [w3schools](http://w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp) notes that this doesn't work properly on IE 8.0 and earlier.

Comment: @bonsaiviking offtopic: please read [this](http://w3fools.com/) before referencing that site again

Answer (score 3):

```
overflow: auto;
white-space: nowrap;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GCPDE/

Answer (score 1):

Change your style to this:

```
style="width: 20px; height:30px; border:1px solid black; overflow:auto;"
```

Just a case of incorrect syntax.

Comment: Oh well, looks like the edited version of your original post is now correct.

Comment: Oh, I edited the question - I thought it was a typo and not the exact code.

Comment: Agreed, I think I'll leave it since clyfish has already added it above.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: In order to make text horizontally scrollable you will have to add 
***overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y: hidden; white-space: nowrap;***  to your div.

```html
<html>
     <body>
        <div style ="width:20px; height:30px; border:1px solid black; overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:hidden; white-space:nowrap;">
            <!-- various of text here that can makes it go out the border-->
        </div>  
     </body>
</html>
```