# horizontal scrollbar in table or list

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

Is there any chance to have a tripartite row, where column one and three have a fixed width of 100px and column two is responsive?
When I try a table, the horizontal scrollbar doesn't appear anymore, if column two gets smaller than 500px. When I try a list (*float: left* or *display: inline-block*) it's the same problem.

```css
#div_scroll {
    width: auto;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

#p_scroll {
 width:500px
}
```

```html
<div id="div_scroll">
  <p id="p_scroll">
    m ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

p_scroll needs to be larger than div_scroll for this to work.

In other words:
DOM inside scrollable DOM needs to be larger for a scrollbar to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page which discussed horizontal scroll bars, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925284/horizontal-scrollbar).

I don't think you want that p_scroll at all, that or move the overflow stuff into the p_scroll because you have one thing saying auto width and another setting a width to a specific amount.

Like listed on that page you will also want to add `white-space: nowrap;`