# Tables side by side within div plus horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, css

I am dynamically generating N tables. I don't know how many there will be ahead of time (nor the # of rows or columns, although I could compute that before I attempt to render the tables, if necessary).

According to the spec, the tables must be side by side. When they go over the horizontal width, the page should introduce a horizontal scroll.

I seem to be able to sometimes get one but not the other. What I have right now is a parent `div` with `overflow-x:auto`, and then nested `div` tags with `float:left` for each `<table>`, but to no avail.

There are a few related StackOverflow questions, but none of them solved my issue:

- [HTML — Two Tables Horizontally Side by Side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917235/html-two-tables-horizontally-side-by-side)
- [HTML -- two tables side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690223/html-two-tables-side-by-side/11690480#11690480)
- [horizontal scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13925284/27678)

Code and fiddle below:

```
<div style="width:100px; height:60px; border: 1px solid black; overflow-x: auto; font-size: 14px;float:left">
  <div style="float:left;margin-right:10px">
    <table border=1 cellpadding=10 style="float:left">
      <th>Lorem</th><th>Ipsum</th><th>Sit</th><th>Dolor</th><th>Amet</th>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left;margin-right:10px">
    <table border=1 cellpadding=10 style="float:left">
      <th>Lorem2</th><th>Ipsum2</th><th>Si2t</th><th>Dolor2</th><th>Amet2</th>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### [Live Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bsod7ejm/)

How can I simultaneously write two or more tables side by side with a horizontal scroll if the content becomes too wide?

---

**Edit**: The answers below work great, just be wary that running Internet Explorer with compatibility mode turned on will not work (To check, you can "Inspect Element" and navigate to "Document Mode" to see if it says something like "5" (bad) or "Edge" (good))

Comment: You can simply add `display: flex` on parent and remove unnecessary `float`s from child elements. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bsod7ejm/3/)

Comment: @MohammadUsman: Your fiddle and Jonathan's answer seem to work great in Chrome, but are there known issues with IE11? It appears to only give me vertical scroll.

Comment: @AndyG In my IE11 its working fine. However if `flexbox` doesn't suit your needs, you can use the other variant posted by @Jonathan.

Comment: @AndyG I found the IE11 scroll problem and updated my answer.

Comment: @AndyG Have you tried my answer? using `display:inline-table;` won't affect the natural flow/behavior of `table`.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey, Mohammad Usman: Hilariously, none of the solutions work for the version of IE I am forced to use (I have no control over it, and it's likely been "customized" quite a bit). The "uncustomized" version of Chrome I use seems fine. I like the `inline-table` approach.

Comment: @AndyG even when you remove the `height:60px` you still have a vertical scrollbar in IE?

Comment: @Jonathan: Yes. It looks like it's running in an IE5 compatibility mode. Grrr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flexbox`.

```css
div {
  overflow-x: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

table {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table border=1 cellpadding=10 cellspacing=0>
    <tr>
      <th>Lorem</th>
      <th>Ipsum</th>
      <th>Sit</th>
      <th>Dolor</th>
      <th>Amet</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Lorem</th>
      <th>Ipsum</th>
      <th>Sit</th>
      <th>Dolor</th>
      <th>Amet</th>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <table border=1 cellpadding=10 cellspacing=0>
    <th>Lorem2</th>
    <th>Ipsum2</th>
    <th>Si2t</th>
    <th>Dolor2</th>
    <th>Amet2</th>
  </table>
</div>
```

---

Or you can also use `display:inline-table;` and `white-space: nowrap;` to parent, there is no need for floats I guess.

```css
div {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 100%;
}

table {
  margin: 0 10px;
  display:inline-table;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table border=1 cellpadding=10 cellspacing=0>
    <tr>
      <th>Lorem</th>
      <th>Ipsum</th>
      <th>Sit</th>
      <th>Dolor</th>
      <th>Amet</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Lorem</th>
      <th>Ipsum</th>
      <th>Sit</th>
      <th>Dolor</th>
      <th>Amet</th>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <table border=1 cellpadding=10 cellspacing=0>
    <th>Lorem2</th>
    <th>Ipsum2</th>
    <th>Si2t</th>
    <th>Dolor2</th>
    <th>Amet2</th>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can put a `white-space:nowrap` on the outer div and replace the `float:left` with a `display:inline-block` on the inner divs:

To remove the vertical scrollbar on IE11, remove the `height:60px;` on the outer div.

```html
<div style="width:100px; border: 1px solid black; overflow-x: auto; font-size: 14px;float:left; white-space: nowrap">
  <div style="display:inline-block;margin-right:10px">
    <table border=1 cellpadding=10 style="float:left">
      <th>Lorem</th><th>Ipsum</th><th>Sit</th><th>Dolor</th><th>Amet</th>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;margin-right:10px">
    <table border=1 cellpadding=10 style="float:left">
      <th>Lorem2</th><th>Ipsum2</th><th>Si2t</th><th>Dolor2</th><th>Amet2</th>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bsod7ejm/1/

Also, if you want no space between the tables, you could put a `font-size:0;` on the parent div and a `font-size:12px` (or whatever you want) on the inner divs.  I'd also recommend using a stylesheet instead of inline styles:

```css
.outer {
  width:100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-x: auto;
  font-size: 14px;
  float:left;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.inner {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:10px;
}

.inner table {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <table border=1 cellpadding=10>
      <th>Lorem</th><th>Ipsum</th><th>Sit</th><th>Dolor</th><th>Amet</th>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <table border=1 cellpadding=10>
      <th>Lorem2</th><th>Ipsum2</th><th>Si2t</th><th>Dolor2</th><th>Amet2</th>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```